# Pushing to Heroku Fails - sinon-mongoose, grpc, node-pre-gyp

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

Up until yesterday I could push to Heroku. Currently, I'm getting my push to Heroku rejected with the following error message:

```
Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
yarn install v1.3.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > sinon-mongoose@1.3.0" has incorrect peer dependency "sinon@1".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
error /tmp/build_592ecabd23ba493189b9cac8d/node_modules/multer-gcs/node_modules/grpc: Command failed.
Exit code: 127
Command: ./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
Arguments:
Directory: /tmp/build_592ecabd23ba493189b9cac8d/node_modules/multer-gcs/node_modules/grpc
Output:
/bin/sh: 1: ./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp: not found
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

The strange thing is that `node-pre-gyp` is there in the file path specified. How can I get my push to work? I've also tried updating the `package.json`, specifying the versions for `engines.node`, `engines.npm`, `engines.yarn`, since these were mentioned in the error message.

**UPDATE:**

I now know that the issue is coming from `gcloud` (`"gcloud":"^0.37.2";`)
, since I temporarily removed that module from `package.json` and pushed again and the push went through without the error message.

Comment: Is the git repo available for testing?

Comment: No unfortunately it's not @TarunLalwani

Comment: See https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1817

Comment: `grpc` is the one causing the issue, the reason why you don't have the error when you remove `gcloud` is because `gcloud` depends on `grpc`, try reinstalling `grpc` and upgrade `yarn` as `node-pre-gyp: not found` is fixed in 1.7.2