# Can't push to Heroku because of "grpc"

Tags: node.js, heroku, grpc

I'm trying to push the changes to my NodeJS web app to heroku; however, I encounter the following error message during the build phase. I know the issue lies with "grpc" (refer to the error message), which I suspect is a dependency of firebase; however, I don't know how to resolve the issue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313602/pushing-to-heroku-fails-sinon-mongoose-grpc-node-pre-gyp) is a very similar issue I found on SO but there is no clear solution on that thread.

```
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        error /tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/node_modules/grpc: Command failed.
remote:        Exit code: 1
remote:        Command: ./node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
remote:        Arguments:
remote:        Directory: /tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/node_modules/grpc
remote:        Output:
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.4.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@10.4.0 (node-v64 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
remote:        CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
remote:        sed: can't read ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw: No such file or directory
remote:        rm: cannot remove './Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw': No such file or directory
remote:        grpc.target.mk:394: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o' failed
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:        make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o] Error 1
remote:        gyp ERR! build error
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:237:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1019-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_5dcbc8b8883705e76971dd8574f59db8/node_modules/grpc
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v10.4.0
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
```

**SOLVED:**

Follow the instructions at this [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/467)

> OK :) firebase 4.6.2 firebase-admin 5.3.0 firebase-tools 3.7.0
>
> KO :( firebase 4.7.0 + firebase-admin 5.4.0 + firebase-tools 3.8.0 +
>
> At this stade you might think older versions could work with
>   firestore. But, if you want to use firestore, it will claim the grpc
>   node module, and if you yarn it, same error :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary problem here is that the version of gRPC you are trying to install is not compatible with the version of Node that you are using. That error indicates that you are installing gRPC@1.10.1 with Node 10; the first version of gRPC that supports Node 10 is gRPC@1.11.1. So, in general the solution to this problem would be to either downgrade your Node version, or upgrade your gRPC version.

Your edit seems to indicate that you were able to solve this by downgrading the versions of the `firebase`, `firebase-admin`, and `firebase-tools` packages that you are using. This probably works because the specific versions you tried first pinned the gRPC dependency to the older version, and downgrading got you a version that didn't have the dependency pinned. However, each of those packages also has newer versions that don't pin the gRPC dependency and should give you the newest version.

Comment: Thank you, I can confirm that updating firebase and firebase-admin to ^5.0.4 and ^5.12.1 respectively (the latest versions right now) works as you anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the node and npm versions in my package.json fixed it for me. These have to be the same as the ones on your local machine ie. `"engines":{"node": "^10.16.0","npm": "^6.9.0"}` and creating a .npmrc file and including this line `engine-strict=true`. This ensures that your app will be running in the same environment.